# Python Terminology of "pairs"

Tags: python

I sort of learned backyard python without all of the fancy terminology, and I came across this description of a pickled file...

"The pickled file represents a tuple of 3 lists : the training set, the validation set and the testing set. **Each of the three lists is a pair formed from a list of images and a list of class labels for each of the images.** An image is represented as numpy 1-dimensional array of 784 (28 x 28) float values between 0 and 1 (0 stands for black, 1 for white). The labels are numbers between 0 and 9 indicating which digit the image represents."

(From http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/gettingstarted.html)

I'm trying to visualize it in my head (this is the format they want pickled so I cant just modify it), does that mean that the file is

(1) Three Lists, Each of which is made up of two lists, one with images, and one with labels,

(2) Three Lists, Each of which is composed of tuples, with (tuple[0] being image and tuple[1] being label)

or something else?

Comment: My guess is that pair means a 2-element sequence, i.e. you can do `pair[0]` and `pair[1]`.

Comment: You can bet on (2) - a pair is typically a tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can investigate the topology of the data:

```
In [1]: import cPickle
In [2]:
In [3]: f = cPickle.load(open('mnist.pkl', 'rb'))

In [4]: type(f)
Out[4]: tuple

In [5]: len(f)
Out[5]: 3

In [6]: type(f[0])
Out[6]: tuple

In [7]: len(f[0])
Out[7]: 2

In [8]: type(f[0][0])
Out[8]: numpy.ndarray

In [9]: len(f[0][0])
Out[9]: 50000

In [10]: f[0][0].shape
Out[10]: (50000, 784)
```

Comment: This implies...

(([],[]),([],[]),([],[])) yes? (Where [] is the numpy arrays)

Comment: The `pprint` module might also be helpful. http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Comment: Not really: each of your 2-tuples is actually a list of 2-tuples. So each list has a tuple. The first entry in the tuple is a numpy array. In this array contains 50000 images of 784 float values. The second entry is probably a list of size 50000 with 50000 labels.

Comment: That isn't what the output shows, there is no list type shown. How do you know that?

Comment: Ya sorry I got confused ><

Answer (score 2):

```
training_set is ([image,image,image,...],[label,label,label,...])
validation_set is ([image,image,image,...],[label,label,label,...])
testing_set is ([image,image,image,...],[label,label,label,...])
```

put together as one triple:

```
(
    ([image,image,image,...],[label,label,label,...]),
    ([image,image,image,...],[label,label,label,...]),
    ([image,image,image,...],[label,label,label,...])
)
```

The "learner" will teach itself from the training set, then validate what it has learned from the validation set, then the testing set is meant to be "real-world" live data.